# Adding GZIP with Rack::Deflator causes "Client Request Interrupted" errors on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Adding GZIP with Rack::Deflator causes a lot of "Client Request Interrupted" errors (H27) on Heroku (around 1% of all requests with no obvious pattern).

Any idea what can be causing this? And how to fix it?

```
> rails middleware

use Rack::Cors
use ActionDispatch::SSL
use RackReverseProxy::Middleware
use Rack::Sendfile
use ActionDispatch::Static
use Rack::Deflater
use ActionDispatch::Executor
use ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware
use Rack::Timeout
...
```

Rack:Deflator gzips only html. The rest are served from CDN.

Answer (score 1):

You can use heroku deflater gem too. That is specific for heroku platform.

```
gem 'heroku-deflater', :group => :production
```